# tomcat8 is running, but no pid file

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I recently started working on a project that is running in an AWS instance using tomcat. I need to restart tomcat every once in a while, and I was told by their original owners that the following command would do the trick

```
$ sudo service tomcat8 restart
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, and I get the following error:

```
tomcat8 running, but no pid file^[[60G[^[[0;31mFAILED^[[0;39m]
Starting tomcat8: ^[[60G[^[[0;31mFAILED^[[0;39m]
```

More than just finding a workaround to restart it with other commands, I would like to know if there's a way to make that command work properly 'cause there must be something off and I don't seem to find what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to run over the same issue, freeing up space might solve it, it did for me.

Comment: Hi @Camilo, how to free up space? I am getting same error, I wanted to increase heap size limit but it didn't.

Comment: Hey @efirat , In my case I deleted some logs that were supposed to rotate but didn't... and that solved it... So it wasn't a tomcat problem but more like a server issue, so first check out if you have a fair amount of free space in the server.

Comment: I have faced this error in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk servers. I have changed Tomcat and platform version to previous one, and it has been solved, for me. Later, I will investigate why last version (3.0.1) is problematic.